# Retrieve elements using $slice

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

**My result is following after executing find() query.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5384928a03ea2e75268b4567"),
    "0" : {
        "name" : "mango",
        "quantity" : "10"
     },
    "1" : {
        "name" : "apple",
        "quantity" : "14"
     },
    "2" : {
        "name" : "banana",
        "quantity" : "11"
     },
    "3" : {
        "name" : "grapes",
        "quantity" : "19"
     },
    "4" : {
        "name" : "lichi",
        "quantity" : "13"
     },
    "5" : {
        "name" : "orange",
        "quantity" : "10"
     },
    "6" : {
        "name" : "lemon",
        "quantity" : "10"
     },
    "7" : {
        "name" : "pear",
        "quantity" : "10"
     },
    "8" : {
        "name" : "cherry",
        "quantity" : "10"
     },
    "9" : {
        "name" : "kiwi",
        "quantity" : "10"
    }
}
```

**Now i want only any five elements in result(like from 2nd element to 6th element).**

**How to do this using $slice or is there any other method to retrieve only five elements in result?**

Comment: Does your data actually look like this from the mongo shell or are abstracting this in a very PHP way. If this is from the shell the data is not actually in an array, but these are sub-documents with the "indexes" as the key names.

Comment: I am putting this in database through php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing here is, do you actually have an array for [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to work on? There seems to be a bit of a misconception here common to people working with PHP as the way that language typically represents an array.

The mongo shell ( for example ) will show the clear distinction, where an array actually looks like this in it's JSON representation:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5384928a03ea2e75268b4567"),
    "arrayField": [
        {
            "name" : "mango",
            "quantity" : "10"
        },
        {
            "name" : "apple",
            "quantity" : "14"
        },
        {
            "name" : "banana",
            "quantity" : "11"
        },
        {
            "name" : "grapes",
            "quantity" : "19"
        }
    ]
}
```

That structure can use the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator to return the elements you want. As an example here, 2 documents from index position 1

```js
db.collection.find({},{ "arrayField": { "$slice": [ 1,2] }})

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5384928a03ea2e75268b4567"), 
    "arrayField" : [ 
        { "name" : "apple", "quantity" : "14" }, 
        { "name" : "banana", "quantity" : "11" }
    ]
}
```

The structure you are showing is just a bunch of key names for sub-documents within the top level document. It is probably a mistake but you just specify those fields in the projection. It's not an array so [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) does not apply:

```js
db.collection.find({}, { "1": 1, "2": 1, "3": 1, "4": 1, "5": 1, "6": 1 })
```

But that probably is not what you want, so it looks like you will need to fix your data so it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

$slice is used to control the number of elements in an array returned by the query, but I don't see an explicit array in your results.  Your document should look something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5384928a03ea2e75268b4567"),
    "fruit" : [
      {
        "name" : "mango",
        "quantity" : "10"
      },
      {
        "name" : "apple",
        "quantity" : "14"
      }
    ]
}
```

Then you could query it with something like:
    db.collection.find({},{"fruit": {$slice:[1:6]}})

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only 5 record from document you can use limit(), if you want to skip few of the record then use skip().

For Example :

> db.collection.find().skip(2).limit(5);

This query fetch 5 documents after first 2 documents.

Comment: Why is this absolute garbage up-voted? It is completely irrelevant to the question. LOL To serial up-voters looking for badges. It's not about `n` records, the question asked about extracting `n` items from a "single" document. And clearly had problems in itself. My personal award the the most stupid answer on stackoverflow this month. Let's watch the down-votes roll in.

Comment: plz Read my question carefully.